# Extract a path from text file using sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed

`one.txt` contents as below.

```
Hi this is the first line in a file one.txt
cooler:some default cooler string `/var/log/cooler_x86_64_someos8.4/config.cf'
doing good nice!
all is well
Hi this is the lastline in a file one.txt
```

Expected output

```
/var/log/cooler_x86_64_ubantu.8.24/config.cf
```

I need as below

```
cat one.txt | grep cooler | sed somergexp
```

---

Clarification:

Yes first is back quote and end is single quote

```
`/var/log/cooler_x86_64_someos8.4/config.cf'
```

I could able to do with using two `sed`'s as below

```
sed 's:^.*\(`.*\)'\''.*$:\1:'| sed 's/`//'
```

but need to do with a single `sed` call.

Comment: can u confirm the single quote at the end of second line in one.txt... I suspect it should be a backtick.

Comment: So you want to extract the path and also change `someos` to `ubanto`?

Answer (score 0):

i could able to solve the issue with `sed 's:[^/]*\(.*\)'\''.*$:\1:'`

Comment: This correctly picks out the pathname from the line where it occurs, but it also prints out all other lines from the given text. It also does weird things with an extra line if it says, for example, `Is this good/bad? It's hard to say.`

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed -n -r '/^cooler/s|.*['\''`"]([^'\''"`]+).*|\1|gp' one.txt
```

`-n` silent
`/^cooler/` pattern
`gp` - output result
`` .*['\''`"] `` - character group before quotation marks('`")
`` ([^'\''"`]+) `` - a group of characters after the quotation mark, except for the following quotation marks('`")

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by picking out the line of interest.  That line starts with the string `cooler:`:

```
$ sed -e '/^cooler:/!d' file
cooler:some default cooler string `/var/log/cooler_x86_64_someos8.4/config.cf'
```

The expression `/^cooler:/!d` would delete all lines from the input that does not match `/^cooler:/`.

Then we extract the thing between a backquote and a quote:

```
$ sed -e '/^cooler:/!d' -e "s/.*\`\([^']*\)'.*/\1/" file
/var/log/cooler_x86_64_someos8.4/config.cf
```

The expression `` s/.*\`\([^']*\)'.*/\1/ `` substitutes the whole line with the string within `` `...' ``.  The backquote needs to be escaped since this expression is within double quotes (it would be the start of a command substitution in the shell otherwise).

You could also do the extraction of the path in two steps: Remove everything up to and including the backquote, and then remove everything after and including the single quote.  This may even look a bit tidier:

```
$ sed -e '/^cooler:/!d' -e 's/.*`//' -e "s/'.*//" file
/var/log/cooler_x86_64_someos8.4/config.cf
```

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of variations on Regular Expressions

1. Using `sed`

   ```
   sed -n '/^cooler:/s/^.*`\(.*\)'"'"'/\1/p'
   ```

   This can be explained as follows

   - `-n` don't print anything unless there is a match
   - `^cooler:` look for `cooler:` at the beginning of the line
   - `s/old/new/p` replace `old` with `new` and print result if the substitution succeeded
   - `` ^.*`\(.*\)'"'"' `` matches everything to the backtick, then captures everything inside the brackets  `(` ... `)`, then captures a singlequote to the end of the line. The `'"'"'` is shell fluff - the first `'` ends the initial single-quoted string, the `"'"` quotes a single-quote, the final `'` restarts a single-quoted string
   - `\1` in the replacement part references the captured string from the pattern match
2. Using GNU `grep`

   ```
   grep -oP '^cooler:.*`\K'"[^']*"
   ```

   This can be explained in much the same way as before

   - `-oP` only print the match, and use perl regular expressions (PCRE) for parsing
   - `\K` a boundary: everything before this is matched but discarded; everything afterwards is included in the result
   - `[^']*` matches everything except a single-quote

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -ne '
   /^cooler:/y/`'\''/\n\n/
   s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p
' one.txt
```

This is posix sed and we change quote n back quote to newlines. Then the path is 
Sandwiched between the two newlines.

Answer (score 0):

To extract text between outer-most matching pairs of `` `...' ``, you can do:

```
pcregrep -o2 "(\`((?:(?1)|[^\`']++)*+)')"
```

Using perl-style recursive matching.

Or:

```
perl -lne "print for /(\`((?:(?1)|[^\`']++)*+)')/g"
```

Or to restrict to the ones starting with `/`:

```
perl -lne "for (/(\`((?:(?1)|[^\`']++)*+)')/g) {print if m{^/}}"
```